# Gstreamer AudioSink plugin development

Tags: c, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I'm currently developing a gstreamer audiosink plugin, but I am facing some synchronization problems with the _write() function.

The problem is that the write requests and are too fast so the data inside the function end up being silence. I'm not finding a proper way to wait for the buffer to have data in it's segment.

What I'm doing is to make a fixed sleep(g_usleep) in each write, but this is not a solution, can you guys help me? Thanks

Comment: Please post the relevant code here.